# Extract all link in a json file

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python at the moment i managed to get a huge json file,
i want to extract from it all the links and download them.

```
import json
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/top/.json'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
suffix = ['.jpg','.png','.gif','.bmp']
while True:
    response = http.request('GET',url)
    myData = response.data
    parsedJson = json.loads(myData)
    finalUrl = parsedjson[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']
    print(finalUrl)
```

at the moment i get an error on the line of finalUrl so i think i'm having an error trying to get each url in the json file.

source: https://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/top/.json

Comment: Maybe `finalUrl = parsedjson['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']` ?

Comment: This is returning me the same one link instead of many different links

Comment: @Arun Could you check the json file, maybe you can figure out how i can access to the link.
Like i told with your suggestion instead of getting all the links i'm getting the first url link in an infinite loop.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you verify that it works?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a loop to go through all the links

```
for i in parsedjson['data']['children']: 
    finalUrl =i['data']['url']
    print(finalUrl)
```

#### Output

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHAf3.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/szj6wnw2foi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/5k8vgy173mi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaMch.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/9nab5nvi4mi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/9zgnp3z1gmi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/ulhtdcomsoi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/yjthueewmmi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/gtdm76o3yni11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/1j7ez5alloi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.imgur.com/8xNGW6T.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/13fk1b3rhki11.jpg
>   
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCRXi.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/qqfb57u53ni11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/17fs1whd3pi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/kjwv5p15qni11.png
>   
> https://i.redd.it/oayns08fjqi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/10mMp.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/px53p4e2ski11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/ncjytopnami11.jpg
>   
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6njE.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/ecbs9yao5ni11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/10210k2rpli11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/xxs7h8ng1qi11.jpg
>   
> https://i.redd.it/5toz9ercjni11.jpg

Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Check if the 0s that you use are keys or just list indices.  You may have to use '0' for the second [0].

In your code:

```
finalUrl = parsedjson[0]['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']
```

Suggestion:

```
finalUrl = parsedjson[0]['data']['children']['0']['data']['url']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you please check the json file, because i think my main error is how to access to the link, same error with your response .

Comment: Try this : finalUrl = parsedjson['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are not iterating through all the children in the response. So you need to change the code to:

```
import json
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/EarthPorn/top/.json'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
suffix = ['.jpg','.png','.gif','.bmp']
response = http.request('GET', url)
myData = response.data
parsedJson = json.loads(myData)
for children in parsedjson['data']['children']:
    finalUrl = children['data']['url']
    print(finalUrl)
```